# Logging statement security issue

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I'm doing code analysis for JavaScript code using SonarQube. The analysis was complaining about this line of code:

```
    if (this.isDebug) {
        console.log("[DEBUG: " + message);
    }
```

with this message:

> **Console logging should not be used.**
>
> Debug statements are always useful
>   during development. But include them in production code - particularly
>   in code that runs client-side - and you run the risk of inadvertently
>   exposing sensitive information, slowing down the browser, or even
>   erroring-out the site for some users.

Now, if I change `console.log` to `console.info`, I don't have the previous warning. But, for my understanding, `log` and `info` are equivalent.

1. Would using `info` be the right fix?
2. What would be the best approach to fix this security issue?

Comment: @tadman info and log are equivalent. Why sonarqube is not complaining about info?

Comment: If it's anything like [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) or [Code Climate](https://www.codeclimate.com) it has its reasons. Maybe this is for auditing browser code that can become unexpectedly chatty.

Answer (score 2):

Code analysis tools want to generate a lot of output, so you feel like you're getting your money's worth from using them.  You still need to apply your own common sense to their recommendations.

All they're really warning you about here is that end users who know how to open the console will be able to see whatever you log to the console.    They presumably didn't bother to add the same warning to `console.info` because `console.info` is relatively underused (though, as you point out, it is functionally equivalent to `console.log`.)

There's a mixture of fact and fiction in their warning:

> you run the risk of inadvertently exposing sensitive information

That part's true. (For some values of "sensitive".  Strictly speaking, assuming the code is running clientside, any information being logged on the console would also be available to end users by digging through the code, but it's a lot simpler to read the console.  If the code *isn't* running clientside then it really makes no difference whether you call `console.log` or not.)

> slowing down the browser,

Technically true, but not terribly relevant in most real-world situations.  If you're logging tons and tons of data, the browser does need to take the time to print that data into the console (though I believe this is only the case if the console is open at the time.)   It would take quite a bit of logging before this should have noticeable effects.

> or even erroring-out the site for some users.

I'm going to go ahead and call that part nonsense: I'm not aware of any browser so fragile that simply calling `console.log` can cause errors.

#### Your questions

> Would using info be the right fix?

If all you care about is making the warning go away, sure, use `.info()`;  it won't fix anything other than making the warning go away, but depending on what you're logging there may not be a problem to fix in the first place.

> What would be the best approach to fix this security issue?

Ideally, a build pipeline that strips out console messages so you don't have to remember to remove them yourself; and that differentiates between dev and production environments so you don't have to code in flags like `this.isDebug`.

Failing that, review your code to make sure you're not logging anything that could be considered sensitive.  In your case, since the log call is wrapped in a debug flag, you'd want to ensure that `this.isDebug` never gets set to true in a production environment.

Comment: > "or even erroring-out the site for some users."


SonarQube is referring to old IE mostly for browsers that don't support `console` at all.  

This used to throw an error in Micro$oft products, but Edge is chromium, now, so for the most part, this is indeed a non-issue in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a common js logger util  to log all types of errors/custom information.

call that common function from your all code exception blocks or debug blocks.

Using this way if you want to log somewhere else then only need to change in logger util js only.